# how to stop ldap search when result is found

Tags: java, spring-ldap, ldap-query

I am trying to get loggedin user's group name from distinguishedName parameter. I can find the group name but search is countine, even if i find the person in ldap search and in the and gets

**PartialResultException: Unprocessed Continuation Reference(s);**

Here is My code

I want to stop `ldapTemplate.search` process when I got a successful result do you guys have any idea ?

```
public List<String> getUserGroup(String username) throws Exception {
        try {
            LdapQuery query;
            LdapTemplate ldapTemplate = ldapConf.ldapTemplate();
            if (ldapConf.getSearchBase().isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("searchbase empty");
                query = query().where(env.getProperty("retouch.ldap.searchKeyword")).isPresent();
            } else
                query = query().base(ldapConf.getSearchBase()).where(env.getProperty("retouch.ldap.searchKeyword")).isPresent();
            List<String> result = ldapTemplate.search(query, new AttributesMapper<String>() {
                public String mapFromAttributes(Attributes attrs) throws NamingException, javax.naming.NamingException {

                    for (Enumeration vals = attrs.get("distinguishedName").getAll(); vals.hasMoreElements();) {
                        String userName = (String) vals.nextElement();
                        if (userName.contains(username)) {
                            return (String) attrs.get("distinguishedName").get();
                        }
                    }

                    return null;
                }
            });
            logger.debug("ldap groups" + result);
            while (result.remove(null)) {
            }
            return result;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            logger.error(e, e);
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

Comment: If if you stopped the search on the client side, the operation would not be stopped on the server side. Not even if you send an 'ABANDON' operation.

Comment: Your search should only return one element if you've written it right. Rather than having it return an entire table and then searching it yourself at the client, as you appear to be doing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I totally misunderstood ldap search mechanism. My ldap query was also wrong

`query = query().where(env.getProperty("ldap.searchKeyword")).isPresent();`

instead of `isPresent()` I should have used `is(username)` so I can directly get the user that I want. Also I was trying to get user DN in my code. Instead of `new AttributesMapper<String>()` , `new ContextMapper<String>()` provide the DN